# How to skip leading whitespace in input stream C++?

Tags: c++, string, whitespace, getline

I have a file that looks like this:

```
Category ID         Description
1                   Pay Check
2                   Groceries
3                   Utilities
14                  Rent
25                  Mortgage
6                   Travel
7                   Refund
8                   Restaurant
9                   College Fund
10                  Transfer From Savings
```

I created an input file stream to read in the Category ID, then used getline() to read the Description.
My problem is that whenever using getline() to read the Description into strings, it keeps the whitespace before the actual string.  Is there any way to ignore the whitespace when storing it?

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, can you please click the checkmark next to it to accept it? It helps a lot! :D

Answer (score 7):

Use `std::ws`:

```
while (std::getline(in >> std::ws, line))
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```